# Правильно ли оформлена прямая речь? (2)

Tags: прямая-речь

– Что? Какой обод... – незнакомка недоумевающе схватилась за голову, нащупывая рукой золотистую полоску металла, инкрустированного редкими стразами. – Ах это... это мама настояла. Говорит, что очень подходит к моим глазам, – после чего и без того красноватое лицо девочки сделалось румяно-алым, а на губах наконец-то просияла лёгкая улыбка. – Глупо как-то получилось, – почесала она смущённо макушку, – пришла, вывалила на тебя всё это, а сама даже не сказала, как меня зовут. Я Ангелия. Родом из небольшого городка, что граничит с Мексикой. Улавливаешь? – девочка загадочно улыбнулась Кэти, словно ожидая одобрения, отчего той стало неловко, и она автоматически кивнула, хотя совершенно не смыслила в географии.

Comment: Вроде да, правильно.

Comment: На абзацы не разбивать — сверхзадача?

Comment: Обычно с государством граничат государства, а не... городки.

Comment: «Инкрустированного редкими стразами»? Стразы — литое стекло, хрусталь или акрил с покрытием. Резать литое, подгоняя под нужный формат не повредив, значит погубить изделие. Покрыть стразами можно, но не инкрустировать. И называть стразы «редкими» в общем случае неправильно по той же самой причине: они льются массово.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ваши замечания. Обязательно их учту. Очень всё полезно и по делу!)

Answer (score 1):

Вот как правильно. (Трудно читается.)

— Что? Какой обод... — незнакомка недоумевающе схватилась за голову, нащупывая рукой золотистую полоску металла, инкрустированного редкими стразами.

— Ах это... это мама настояла. Говорит, что очень подходит к моим глазам, — после чего и без того красноватое лицо девочки сделалось румяно-алым, а на губах наконец-то просияла лёгкая улыбка.

— Глупо как-то получилось, — почесала она смущённо макушку. — Пришла, вывалила на тебя всё это, а сама даже не сказала, как меня зовут. Я Ангелия. Родом из небольшого городка, что граничит с Мексикой. — Улавливаешь? — девочка загадочно улыбнулась Кэти, словно ожидая одобрения, отчего той стало неловко, и она автоматически кивнула, хотя совершенно не смыслила в географии.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень дельная разбивка!

Comment: @Татьяна Лукьянова Интересное деление на абзацы. Это же речь одного персонажа, а похоже на диалог... Какой-то переход вроде бы должен быть. Девочка к кому-то обращается, но его ответную речь мы не слышим. Может, пропуски как-то обозначить, например <...>

Answer (score 1):

*— Что? Какой **обод?..** — **Н**езнакомка недоумевающе схватилась за голову, нащупывая рукой золотистую **полоску** металла, **инкрустированную** редкими стразами. — Ах это... **Э**то мама настояла. Говорит, что очень подходит к моим глазам.*

*И без того красноватое лицо девочки сделалось румяно-алым, а на губах наконец-то просияла лёгкая улыбка.*

*— Глупо как-то получилось, — почесала она смущённо макушку, — пришла, вывалила на тебя **всё**, а сама даже не сказала, как меня зовут. Я Ангелия. Родом из небольшого городка, что **на границе** с Мексикой. Улавливаешь?*

*Девочка загадочно улыбнулась Кэти, словно ожидая одобрения, отчего той стало неловко, и она автоматически кивнула, хотя **ничего** не смыслила* [совершенно не разбиралась] *в географии.*

• Я внесла некоторые изменения в текст и разделила его на абзацы (мне кажется, что так удобнее читать). Использовала рекомендации Розенталя ([Абзацы при прямой речи](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=161#pp161)):

> Но если в тексте от автора описывается действие говорящего лица, то и авторский текст, и последующая прямая речь выделяются в абзацы:
> *— Формула эта может иметь и другой вид, — пояснил профессор.
>
> Он неторопливо подошёл к доске, взял мел и написал что-то новое для нас.
>
> — Вот это и есть другой вариант, — сказал он.*

• Вот, как мне кажется, подходящий пример (Рекс Стаут. Прежде чем я умру):

> — Вы думаете, что я идиотка? — сказала она. — Я отдам деньги вам, а вы передадите их Перриту. Неужели он думает, что я попадусь на такую дешевую уловку?
>
> Она наклонилась вперед.
>
> — Послушайте, — серьезно сказала она, — может быть, вы думаете, что у меня не хватит храбрости для разговора с Перритом? Тогда я вам кое-что покажу. — Она стала расстегивать платье. — Сегодня вечером я была в театре, но, если вы заметили, на мне платье с длинными рукавами. И знаете почему?
>
> Вайолет спустила платье с плеч и освободила одну руку.
>
> — Что вы скажете на это? — cпросила она.